# Get both objects of one generic object

Tags: object, generics, get

I have a method with an input of

```
Function<Line, Color> color
```

How can I get access of the Object Line and of the Object Color.
Because i need some attributes of Line and as well of Color.
color is an object which includes 2 object !? Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have as input, is a functional interface. Functional interfaces are interfaces with a single abstract method. The Function interface takes a value and returns another.

In your example, Function is parameterized to receive an input of type Line and returns an output of type Color.

To answer your question, no, color is not an object which contains two objects. Your function is named color and is basically code that takes an argument and produces a result.

An example of how this would work (replacing Line for Integer and Color for String):

```
Function<Integer, String> changeIntegerToString = i -> i + "";

System.out.println(changeIntegerToString.apply(1));
```

As I understand, you want two types as input. You can use a BiFunction interface, which would look like this:

```
BiFunction<Integer, String, String> combineIntegerAndStringToNewString = (i, s) -> "combination: " + i + s;

System.out.println(combineIntegerAndStringToNewString.apply(2, " test"));
```

In this way, you can take both Line and Color as input and do what you need with their attribures to return a result.